# How to pass data from a Service into a HiltViewModel in Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, composable

I have a simple view model class with a state that is being modified by a function

```
@HiltViewModel
class MapViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    fun addNewLocation(location: Location) {
        val latLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
        state.value.coords?.add(latLng)
        state.value = state.value.copy(
            lastKnownLocation = location
        )
    }

    val state: MutableState<MapState> = mutableStateOf(
        MapState(
            lastKnownLocation = null,
            coords = mutableListOf<LatLng>()
        )
    )
}
```

There's also a `@Composable` component that renders a map, and I want to draw a polyline that is being constructed by using the `coords` field of the `MapState`.

I'm getting current location updates inside a foreground service which is being started from the main activity class which has access to the `viewModel`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
      private val viewModel: MapViewModel by viewModels()
    // ...
```

but I can't get reference to the `viewModel` inside the service.

How can I update the state of the `viewModel` whenever the service is getting a new location?

Answer (score 0):

you can use LiveData for example Define a LiveData object in a separate file `object LocationLiveData : LiveData<Location>()`
then in your service whenerver you got a new location update the value of LocationLiveData

```
LocationLiveData.value = location
```

and in your view model observe the LocationLiveData and update the state of the viewmodel

```
LocationLiveData.observeForever { location ->
        addNewLocation(location)
    }
```

to pass LocationLiveData using daggerHilt first you need to make a module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    // ...

    @Provides
    fun provideLocationLiveData(): LocationLiveData = LocationLiveData
}
```

in your service inject the LocationLiveData like this:

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var locationLiveData: LocationLiveData
```

and for your viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MapViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val locationLiveData: LocationLiveData
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        locationLiveData.observeForever { location ->
            addNewLocation(location)
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: How do I pass the LocationLiveData into the service and into the ViewModel?

Comment: you can use dagger hilt to inject this into Service. first you have to make a module that provides the LocationLiveData then you can inject this into your view model :                  class MapViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val locationLiveData: LocationLiveData
) : ViewModel() {

Comment: I have updated the codes you can use it

Comment: I did what you said with minor changes, and now I'm getting this error 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ...MapViewModel`
`Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: ...MapViewModel> has no zero argument constructor`
I think it happens because I have `private val viewModel: MapViewModel by viewModels()` in the main activity, and since `MapViewModel` constuctor needs an argument - the error happens.